# Presto - Calculating TP90 on daily basis

Tags: sql, presto

I have managed to create a dataset as below from a raw data available and I am looking to generate TP90 value on a daily basis up to that date. My sample data as below

```
PURCHASE_DATE     QTY

2019-01-01        10
2019-01-02        30
2019-01-03        50
....
2019-01-31        20
```

I want to generate a TP90 coulmn with values from QTY column for upto that date for example

```
PURCHASE_DATE        QTY      TP90

    2019-01-01        10      TP90 of QTY till 2019-01-01
    2019-01-02        30      TP90 of QTY till 2019-01-02
    2019-01-03        50      TP90 of QTY till 2019-01-03
    ....
    2019-01-31        20
```

I can use APPROX_PERCENTILE(QTY, 0.9) to generate TP90 but struggling to generate it for a daily basis.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alas, presto, although very good at window functions, apparently does not provide a window `approx_percentile()`.

One option would be to self-join the table and aggregate:

```
select 
    t.purchase_date,
    t.qty,
    approx_percentile(t1.qty, 0.9) tp90
from mytable t
inner join mytable t1
    on t1.purchase_date <= t.purchase_date
group by
    t.purchase_date,
    t.qty
```

---

**Edit**

After receving feedback from Piotr Findeisen: all aggregate functions can be used as window functions, as [explained in the documentation](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/window.html#aggregate-functions). So this should work:

```
select 
    t.purchase_date,
    t.qty,
    approx_percentile(t1.qty, 0.9) over(order by purchase_date) tp90
from mytable t
```

I (and Piotr) would be interested to know if this works properly in your use case.

Comment: See https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/window.html#aggregate-functions -- "All Aggregate Functions can be used as window function ...". If it doesn't work in this case, please file a new issue https://github.com/prestosql/presto/issues/ .

Comment: @PiotrFindeisen: my bad, I missed that part of the documentation... Answer updated, thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 1):

APPROX_PERCENTILE, I have observed generates different values when run multiple times and has an inherit error in it ( as its an approximation). This should be considered when used as it can cause some confusion while quality testing of KPI's.